# How to find the B(x2, y2) poin on a chart knowing the angle, the segment length and point A(x1, y1)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, triangles

How I find the B(x2, y2) in the below chart? I want to draw the Fibonacci Fan lines from point A, knowing the x1 and y1, to point B. The line can be a segment with a length of 200 or a ray line. After the first line, I would like to draw several other lines at different angles from point A(x1, y1) at 38.2°, 50°, and so on. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

[image: chart B(X2, y2)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A consistent convention for bearing
angle should be adopted.

With respect to North or East. The latter is used here. From x-axis positive CCW.

$$ x2= x1+ 200 \cos 315^{\circ}$$
$$ y2= y1+ 200 \sin 315 ^{\circ}$$

Comment: Hello @Narasimham, also I want to point out I have try to use the cos and sin functions (of course not in this order) and the results were not precise. Please allow me a couple of minutes to test your solution.

Comment: It seems to work. There are a few things that still need to be fixed on my backend (like the length because is a ray I receive). Have a nice weekend!